# Expected value of powers of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, expected-value, brownian-motion, finance, moment-generating-functions

At the moment I am following a uni course on Financial mathematics, the current subject is Brownian Motion. A subject I have now encountered a couple of times which I don't really understand is the Expected value of a BM to a power, for example $E[W^2(t)]$, which equals t. This particular example can be solved by rewriting the formula for variance, but I'm looking for a broader way of solving these. I have seen the use of moment generating functions for normal distributions pop up here and there, but my book does not really explain this use of the MGF and I have not found a good explanation of how to use these online as well. Could anyone maybe explain how the MGF should be used in this instance and why it works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [MGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X$ is -as we know- $E[e^{tX}]$. Can you tell me what the second derivative of this function w.r.t. $t$ is when you evaluate this at $t=0$ ? I want to hear you saying voila !

Comment: @KurtG. This equals t! Voila! Thanks a lot

Comment: Let's be precise : $\frac{d}{dt}E[e^{tX}]$ equals $E[Xe^{tX}]$ and the 2nd derivative equals $E[X^2e^{tX}]$. Now set $t=0$. That's it.